# Error in neural net in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I have the following dataframe named `train` in R:

```
rsro xo x1 x2 x3     rv           br
   4  0  0  0  0 8.4467 0.3337061885
   1  1  0  0  0 8.0676 0.3435027205
   0  0  0  0  0 9.0288 0.2894759898
   0  1  0  1  0 8.7164 0.3014924009
   0  2  0  0  0 7.9183 0.3894641113
```

I'm training a neural net algorithm with this call:

```
nn=neuralnet(rsro ~ xo + x1 + x2 + x3 + rv + br, 
             data=train, linear.output=F, hidden = c(4,2))
```

But I get this error:

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
>    requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

I have checked all my variables, and there are no missing values and they are all numeric. There have been [several other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457028/working-with-neuralnet-in-r-for-the-first-time-get-requires-numeric-complex-ma?lq=1) here about this error, but all seemed to be solved by eliminating missing or non-numeric values. How do I fix this?

Comment: With the data you provided it works for me. Do you get the error with your sample data? Can you provide `str(train)`? Are you using `neuralnet::neuralnet`?

Comment: This works for me too.  I did notice when I typed `library(neuralnet)` that a few `objects` (like `select` from `dplyr`) were masked.  It could be possible that libraries loaded after `neuralnet` are masking objects in `neuralnet`.