# R neural Networks

Tags: r, neural-network, data-analysis

I am playing around with Adult Dataset
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult and R. I am trying to use the `neuralnet` package to train a Neural Network with Back propagation. I have cleaned the data. Now I am trying to run this part :

```
n <- names(cleanTrain)
f <- as.formula(paste("income~", paste(n[!n %in% "income"], collapse = " + ")))
nn <- neuralnet(f, data=cleanTrain, hidden = 10, algorithm = "backprop", learningrate=0.35)
```

I get this ERROR:

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

P.S:

1. I load the train as cleanTrain
2. n gets all the names of the dataset
3. f returns  `income ~ age + workclass + education + education.num + marital.status + occupation + relationship + race +sex + capital.gain + capital.loss + hours.per.week + native.country`

Which is the error?

Comment: Check your data types for each column?

Comment: What do you mean? 
It has to be only numerical values for example?

Comment: Try with a simpler formula first like `income ~ age` and see if your model runs. Assuming it does, you can add variables one at a time until you find the one that causes the issue. If I had to guess, you might need to switch anything that's a `factor` to `character` but I haven't worked with this library, so that's just a guess.

Comment: Ok! 
Thank you for your Time ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello first use a function to clean the Adult database, which you can find at [Statistical Consulting Group](http://scg.sdsu.edu/dataset-adult_r/), then convert all the variables into numeric, if the backpropagation algorithm does not work. You can see an example at [neural net in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457028/working-with-neuralnet-in-r-for-the-first-time-get-requires-numeric-complex-ma). Finally apply the algorithm with the following code.

```
source("http://scg.sdsu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dataprep.r")
train = as.data.frame(sapply(data$train, as.numeric))
train$income = train$income-1

library(neuralnet)
n <- names(train)
f <- as.formula(paste("income~", paste(n[!n %in% "income"], collapse = " + ")))
nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train,hidden=10,err.fct="sse",linear.output=FALSE,algorithm="backprop",learningrate=0.35)
nn
```

I hope it helps you. regards